# ECS service unreachable from cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

We are using ECS EC2 as orchestration of docker conatiners.

Also we are using AWS CLOUDMAP/Service discovery to create endpoints of services.

In one of my cluster we are not able to reach endpoint of any service, including the service running in same cluster.It give me below error

```
    closing conenction 0
    curl (6) could not resolve host xxx-xxx.test.xxx.org.uk
```

When i try with the IP instead of domain name like 1x.1XX.7*.2X:port/healtcheck/path it works for all services.

I have check all security groups and NACLS all looks fine.